How to linearize $\theta$ around $\pi$, for $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ terms using small angle approximations?
I have the following equations of motion:
$$F = (m+M)\ddot{x} + m \ell \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta - m \ell \dot{\theta}^2 \sin \theta$$ $$\text{and}$$
$$0 = (I + m\ell^2) \ddot{\theta} + m\ell \ddot{x} \cos \theta - mg\ell \sin \theta$$
and I wanted to linearize the  equations of motions around $\theta = \pi$, as we have the case of inverted pendulum, on a cart system.
I get that, for state-space form, we have 4 state variables: $x,\   \dot{x}, \ \theta, \ \dot{\theta},$ but what I don't understand is: how to use small angle approximation around $\pi$?
I assumed small angle approximation meant:
$$\sin \theta  \approx \theta \ (= \pi) \quad \text{and} \quad \cos \theta \approx 0,$$
since $\theta$ is miniscule.
Or do I have to do it like: $\sin(\theta + \pi)$ (which becomes $- \sin \theta$ and same for $\cos \theta$)?
I don't quite understand how to use Taylor expansion around $\theta  = \pi$. Is that the only way to do it?
Edit 1:
I know what the formulation for $\sin \theta$ around $0$ of Taylor expansion is, what I don't understand is: how do we do the same for around $\pi$? Do we simply plug in $\theta = \pi$, or $\theta =  \theta + \pi$?
Also, how do we end up using this new Taylor expansion anyways ?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
